# How can i take screenshot of the blackberry home screen from inside my application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How can I take the [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot) of the [Home Screen](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=rJ7&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&ct=mode&cd=2&q=Blackberry%20Home%20Screens&spell=1&sa=X&sout=0&ei=RQCXT6CkIYLTrQfNkrXeDQ&ved=0CCoQxxQ&biw=1304&bih=662&sei=UgCXT4nuPIrirAedg9nxDQ) (Main display screen) of the Blackberry device from inside my application (to use it as a background image in my app)?
I've used [`Display.screenshot(bm)`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29) but it takes screen-shot of the current screen of my application and I need the screen-shot of the Home Screen of my device.

```java
private class CaptureThread extends Thread {

    public CaptureThread() {
    }

    public void run() {
        FileConnection fc = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;

        try {

            // MainScreen objMainScreen=new MainScreen();

            int width = Display.getWidth();
            // int width=objMainScreen.getWidth();
            int height = Display.getHeight();

            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Display.screenshot(bm);

            PNGEncodedImage png = PNGEncodedImage.encode(bm);

            // Save the PNG to the micro SD card.
            fc = (FileConnection) Connector
                    .open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/screenCap.png");

            if (fc.exists()) {
                fc.delete();
            }

            fc.create();

            out = fc.openDataOutputStream();
            out.write(png.getData());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.toString());
        } finally {

            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            if (fc != null) {
                try {
                    fc.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```